# How to write gcov line coverage output to the screen(console) thather than to a file

Tags: c++, gcov

I need to write the gcov line coverage results to the console (as std output) rather than writing to a file. And also I need to output it in the following format. Can anyone help me with this.

```
function:4,1,main
lcount:4,1
lcount:6,1
lcount:9,1
lcount:15,1
```

Comment: Is this a custom data representation format? Can you provide some reference about the data format?

Comment: This is taken by running gcov -i option

Comment: This is taken by running gcov -i option. The format of the output is not very important. The basic need is to print the output to the console rather than to a flat file. Can you help me for that

Comment: Currently it seems there is no option to print to console. You might use a custom shell script which uses cat command to dump the file to the console.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try that. Can you give me some help for that.

Comment: Can you update the question on the steps followed by you currently to extract the said data with a minimal example?